# React Native WebView error "_onLoadingStart"

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, webview, react-native

I'm seeing a strange issue with the React Native webview (0.32.0). Whenever I render a WebView:

```
render() {
  return (
    <WebView/>
  );
}
```

I get an unhandled Javascript error like this:

[image: 3]

This issue seems to be in WebView.ios.js _onLoadingStart "this" is undefined for some reason. What is also strange is that if I create a new react native project WebViews seem to render fine.

Has anyone seen an issue like this in the past?

Comment: should this even work? there is no source to display so nothing is returned.

Comment: the same error occurs when I add a source, I just took it out for simplicity, additionally when I create a fresh project it works fine (with or without a source).

Comment: also, it seems to work after downgrading to 0.31 so something must have changed in RN

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.